# Incorrect prices and currency in Sandbox in subscription based in app purchase

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

I am using this line of code to get all the information about my products from `App Store Connect` via `StoreKit`

`SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)`

I see the correct product, the correct tiers, the correct introductory offers, however, the **price is not correct**

My complaint is specifically of the price being incorrect in the sandbox environment when I am running the app through TestFlight, App Center or directly via XCode.

**What I tried and some observations**

- I checked several other places including Stack Overflow of similar issues and they mentioned that this was a bug from Apple, however, I am wondering if this is still the case or am I doing something wrong ?
- I also tried [Setting up StoreKit testing in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/setting-up-storekit-testing-in-xcode?language=objc), and created a `synced StoreKit configuration file`, however, even the config file seems to be retrieving incorrect prices
- I also tried changing the location settings in the simulator settings and also from Features -> Location in the simulator menu - it still always returned the locale as US regardless of me changing this
- I even saw one place mention that even though the wrong price was returned by StoreKit, the sheet in the simulator when you are about to make a purchase should show the right price, this also does not happen and I only see the wrong price.

So in summary, my question is:
How can I get the correct prices and correct locale (location) showing up in my sandbox environment using a device and / or simulator ?

**Update**

Just to add some more info, I notice that rather than showing me an incorrect price, it is showing me an outdated starting price.

In my app store connect, I have set the current pricing for new subscribers with an introductory offer.

[image: App store connect store kit]

Just as an example, the price here is $5.99 per month and the intro offer is $1.99 per month for the first 6 months.

On my app, the $1.99 introductory offer is sent correctly by StoreKit, but StoreKit doesn't send the original price correctly and sends something other than $5.99, it shows me $3.99 instead.

What it shows me is actually the starting price, which i can see is set here:

[image: App Store Connect StoreKit iOS Swift Incorrect Sandbox pricing]

[image: App Store Connect StoreKit iOS Swift Incorrect Sandbox pricing incorrect]

Here I can see the original price set as $3.99. However, In production, it shows me the proper price that is set up the first image.

Not sure how to fix this for production ?

Comment: @Shwan Frank any luck?